# Best way to use functions.php to filter ACF in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm currently pulling in multiple pieces of content into my posts through an AFC with the value: "section_content". Furthermore, I'm using the code below to clean up my WP posts. How would I modify this filter to also include my ACF?

```
  <?php
/**
* Clean posts from inline styling and unnecessary tags
*/

add_filter( 'the_content', 'clean_post_content' );
function clean_post_content($content) {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        $patterns = array(
        '/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i',                      // Remove inline styling
        '/<\/?font[^>]*>/',                             // Remove font tag
        '/<(p|span)>(?>\s+|&nbsp;|(?R))*<\/\1>/',       // Empty p, span (font tags already removed)
        '/(<h[1-6]>[^<]*)<\/?strong>(.*?<\/h[1-6]>)/',  // h1-6
        );

        $replacements = array(
        '$1',
        '',
        '',
        '$1$2'
        );

        $old_content = '';
        while ($old_content != $content) {
          $old_content = $content;
          $content = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $content);
        }
    }
    return $content;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use ACF [Filters](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/#filters). I usually hook to [`acf/format_value`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acfformat_value/) in order to clean or modify my custom field values before printing them.

You can even hook to certain field types only, like:

```
function acf_brand_trademark( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
    $value = preg_replace( '/Brand /', 'Brand<sup>™</sup> ', $value );
    return $value;
}

add_filter('acf/format_value/type=textarea', 'acf_brand_trademark', 10, 3);
add_filter('acf/format_value/type=text', 'acf_brand_trademark', 10, 3);
```

Hope this helps!